# If Else in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to use If Else conditional in a LINQ query?

Something like

```
from p in db.products
if p.price>0
select new
{
  Owner=from q in db.Users
        select q.Name
}
else
select new
{
   Owner = from r in db.ExternalUsers
            select r.Name
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This might work...

```
from p in db.products
    select new
    {
        Owner = (p.price > 0 ?
            from q in db.Users select q.Name :
            from r in db.ExternalUsers select r.Name)
    }
```

Comment: It'll be interesting to see if that works... if it does, I'd love to see the TSQL (assuming it does eager loading; for lazy loading, probably not too terrible).

Comment: This should work.  The "? :" is translated to a "case" expression and there are subqueries.

Comment: Should isn't does. It be nice to have confirmation that this does work. Very useful if it does.

Comment: @Richard in case if i need to call a function on else condition, is it possible?

Comment: @NithinPaul - probably best if you post a new question, explaining exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RichardEverett i dont think so Richard, its just to know. In your answer, without using this line "from r in db.ExternalUsers select r.Name)" in else condition, can i use a function call to return the desired text?. I think LInq will not allow it right?

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple "if" conditions this way?

Answer (score 11):

I assume from `db` that this is LINQ-to-SQL / Entity Framework / similar (not LINQ-to-Objects);

Generally, you do better with the conditional syntax ( a ? b : c) - however, I don't know if it will work with your different queries like that (after all, how would your write the TSQL?).

For a trivial example of the type of thing you *can* do:

```
select new {p.PriceID, Type = p.Price > 0 ? "debit" : "credit" };
```

You can do much richer things, but I really doubt you can pick the *table* in the conditional. You're welcome to try, of course...

Answer (score 4):

Answer above is not suitable for complicate Linq expression.
All you need is:

```
// set up the "main query"
var test = from p in _db.test select _db.test;
// if str1 is not null, add a where-condition
if(str1 != null)
{
    test = test.Where(p => p.test == str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var result = _context.Employees
                .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                .Where(x => x.ClientId > (clientId > 0 ? clientId - 1 : -1))
                .Where(x => x.ClientId < (clientId > 0 ? clientId + 1 : 1000))
                .Where(x => x.ContractorFlag == employeeFlag);
            return result;
```

If clientId = 0 we want ALL employees,. but for any clientId between 1 and 999 we want only clients with that ID. I was having issues with seperate LINQ statements not being the same (Deleted/Clients filters need to be on all queries), so by add these two lines it works (all be it until we have 999+ clients - which would be a happy re-factor day!!

Answer (score 0):

you should change like this:

```
private string getValue(float price)
{
    if(price >0)
        return "debit";
    return "credit";
}

//Get value like this
select new {p.PriceID, Type = getValue(p.Price)};
```

Answer (score 0):

my example:

```
 companyNamesFirst = this.model.CustomerDisplayList.Where(a => a.CompanyFirst != null ? a.CompanyFirst.StartsWith(typedChars.ToLower())) : false).Select(b => b.CompanyFirst).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LinQ with EF Core, an easy example can be this-

```
var orderedData = await _dbContext.ModelName
                    .OrderBy(c => c.Name.Length.Length > 4 ? c.Name:c.SuperTerm.Name.IndexOf(searchValue))
                    .ThenBy(t => t.Producer)
                    .TolistAsync();
```