# LINQ Returns Conditional Object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a simple LINQ statement that returns a list of objects based on querying an Xml file.

```
        var locations = from s in xdoc.Descendants("RECORD")
                        where IdList.Contains(s.Element("ID1").Value)
                        select new Location
                                   {
                                       Id = s.Element("ID1").Value
                                   };
```

Each Xml record also has an ID2 element that I want to return if "Contains" is true. So basically, I want my Location object to be conditional based on what the IdList Contains returns (it could be ID1 or ID2). Something like:

```
if(IdList.Contains(s.element("ID1").value){ select new Location {Id = s.Element("ID1").Value};}
if(IdList.Contains(s.element("ID2").value){ select new Location {Id = s.Element("ID2").Value};}
```

Can this be done in a single LINQ statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var locations = from s in xdoc.Descendants("RECORD")
                        select new Location
                                   {
                                       Id = IdList.Contains(s.Element("ID1").Value) ? 
                                       s.Element("ID1").Value : 
                                         (IdList.Contains(s.Element("ID2").Value) ? 
                                          s.Element("ID2").Value : 
                                          DefaultValue)
                                   };
```

If you need the location to contain either ID1 or ID2 just add a where condition

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went ahead and just used two LINQ statements and then merged the results. My object contains quite a few items so the ternary statements got really verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this: [If Else in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443044/if-else-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var locations = from s in xdoc.Descendants("RECORD")
                from x in IdList
                where s.Element("ID1").Value == x || s.Element("ID2").Value == x
                select new Location { Id = x };
```

This should work as long as for each element in `xdoc.Descendants("RECORD")`, `IdList` contains either `s.Element("ID1").Value` or `s.Element("ID2").Value` but not both (otherwise you will get two `Location` objects for that particular record).