# NullReferenceException using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

I have trouble to getting my linq line to work.

```
var result = databaseObjects.Where(dbo => dbo.GetType() == typeof(Model.DatabaseTable) ? (dbo as Model.DatabaseTable).FullName.Equals(name) : dbo.Name.Equals(name));
```

I tried to use the method from an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443044/if-else-in-linq) to make it work.
I think i know what is wrong, DatabaseObject is a abstract class, and i want to to avoid to use FullName property on everything else than DatabaseTable, but from what i can see it does check on it.

EDIT: The Error was:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

Problem was i forgot to assign DatabaseObject.Name, DatabaseTableObject.FullName was assigned.

Comment: i forgot to assign Name, on the objects other than DatabaseTable, a stupid mistake, and i kept looking into the linq expression, which was not wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks as though either `FullName` or `Name` is `null` on one of your dbo objects. To verify change your code to:

```
var result = databaseObjects.Where(dbo => dbo.GetType() == typeof(Model.DatabaseTable) ? (dbo as Model.DatabaseTable).FullName == name : dbo.Name == name);
```

It's shouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: I know found out during maintenence here on stack overflow :) wanted to pull question down before that, but was too slow. Thank you anyway

Comment: Leave the question it may help others.  I would even sugest updating the question to show what error message you were getting.