# Use * as a wildcard when filtering data

Tags: c#, sql

I am looking to perform a search on multiple columns from an access database in C#.
The data is built in rows with each column either holding relevant data or "*" as a wildcard.

So as a rough example:

If i had data that was (, indicates new cell)
Ford, Fiesta, *, 1998
then if i had a value...

Ford, Fiesta, Petrol, 1998

it would find and display the row of data.

Currently I am trying:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [mydatabase]  
WHERE Manufacturer ='" + textBox1.Text +  
"' OR Manufacturer='*' AND Model ='" + textBox2.Text +  
"' OR Model='*' AND Fuel ='" + textBox3.Text +  
"' OR Fuel='*' AND Year='" + textBox4.Text + "' OR Year='*'";
```

But this is bringing up all values rather than filtering them down. Is there a way of using and if/else within the query instead of OR?

Comment: You can have if else statements within a [linq query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443044/if-else-in-linq)

Comment: If you mix `AND` and `OR` you should add parentheses, otherwise `AND` takes precedence over `OR`

Comment: *side note* - your approach is full of sql injection vulnerabilities. use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement#C.23_ADO.NET)

Comment: It looks like `*` is a custom implementation of the database concept of `null`, which databases already support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a wild card, I would just exclude it from the where clauses.

Alternateively, if you want to search all columns as one string you could add them all to a new column in the select list.

for example:

```
        public void GetCars(string manufacturer, string model, string fuel, DateTime? year, string searchString)
        {
            string query = @"
                           SELECT *,
                           ISNULL([Manufacturer],'') + ' ' + ISNULL([Model],'') + ' ' ISNULL([Fuel],'') + ' ' ISNULL('Year', '') AS [SearchString]
                           FROM [MyDatabase]
                           WHERE [Manufacturer]=@Manufacturer ";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
                query += @"AND [Model]=@Model ";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fuel))
                query += "AND [Fuel]=@Fuel ";

            if (year.HasValue)
                query += "AND [Year]=@Year ";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                query += @"AND [SearchString] Like '%@SearchString%' ";

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturer", manufacturer);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", model);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fuel))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fuel", fuel);

                if (year.HasValue)
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year.Value);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchString", searchString);

                //Execute to data table etc
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Manufacturer ='" + textBox1.Text + "' OR Manufacturer='*'`, you can use `coalesce`, which is sort of an `if/else`:

```
string sql = "... Manufacturer = coalesce('" + textBox1.Text + "', '*') ...";
```

In that way, you only need `and`s, and not mixed with `or`. This is probably giving the problem now, since the `or`s cause the `and` not to be evaluated.

You can also add parenthesis around the `and`, so the `or` will be applied only inside the parenthesis:

```
 string sql = "... where (Manufacturer ='" + textBox1.Text + "' OR Manufacturer='*') and ...";
```

Note **you should use [parameterized queries](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)**, so you would get something like this:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from ... where Manufacturer = coalesce(@mgr, '*') and ...";
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("mgr", textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have just tried the coalesce code and it is bringing up an error 'IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)'. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: My bad, Access doesn't support `coalesce`. Can you try `nz` instead of `coalesce`?